# Failed to start nginx - high performance web server

Tags: nginx, yii, yii2

I am trying to install Yii and use Nginx service to run my web application. When i try to do

`sudo systemctl restart nginx.service`, i have an error..

[image]

Then i try to see the status and i get this..

[image]

i found somewhere that i need to run `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to see what is causing the error.. but everything is ok. it says, syntax is ok and test is successful.
[image]

what seems to be the problem with this.. please help.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing this issue on my server. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a process bound to the HTTP port 80 (maybe apache2). You can run command

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

to get a list of processes using the port and then stop/disable web server.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ls -l /usr/share/nginx/` This is where it is looking to save the access logs, check the directory exists and that the user you are running nginx as has write access here.

Comment: hi Luke. Thanks for your reply. When i run the command, i have access.log and error.log file and html which is a directory. what do you mean by has write access here?

Comment: This comes down to unix file permissions, your user 'root' needs the ability to write to the log files, check that you didn't create them as another user first, or that the directory itself you have the write permissions to. `ls -la /usr/share/nginx` . Check out, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm If you include the output of that command it might help understanding your setup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems 80 port is in use, just have a checked, like

`sudo netstat -lnp | grep 0.0.0.0:80`